# How to modify my code to remove (not generate) duplicated permutations

Tags: java, algorithm

I cannot figure out how to recognize that I generate repeated permutation in a recursive call. Let's say we 2 repeated letters in a string of length n. Then I need to create n!/2! sequences, instead of n! sequences.

How to modify my code to achieve this?

```
public class GeneralPermutationGenerator{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "AABC";
        perm(s);
    }

    public static void perm(String s){
        char cs[] = s.toCharArray();
        char result[] = new char[cs.length];
        rperm(cs, result, 0);
    }

    static int j = 1;
    private static void rperm(char[] cs, char[] result, int level){
        if(level == result.length){
            System.out.println(j++ + " " + new String(result));
            return;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++){
            if(cs[i] != 0){
                result[level] = cs[i];
                char temp = cs[i];
                cs[i] = 0;
                rperm(cs, result, ++level);
                cs[i] = temp;
                level--;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The uniqueness can be enforced by always taking a letter that appears multiple times from the first position available.

That is, at each level, when choosing a letter, you can look backward and see if it already occurred in the `cs` array. If it did occur before (which means it was not selected yet, because that position in `cs` is not zero), then it should not be allowed to select it from this position.

---

**Implementation**

One possible implementation involves changing the `rperm` code as follows (looping through the previous characters, to see if the current char was already encountered):

```
private static void rperm(char[] cs, char[] result, int level) {
    if (level == result.length) {
        System.out.println(j++ + " " + new String(result));
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
        if (cs[i] != 0) {
            // first, determine if the current char was already 
            // encountered among the available options
            boolean encountered = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (cs[j] == cs[i]) {
                    encountered = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!encountered) {
                result[level] = cs[i];
                char temp = cs[i];
                cs[i] = 0;
                rperm(cs, result, ++level);
                cs[i] = temp;
                level--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Explanation**

To see how this works, consider again the example `AABC`.

To differentiate the two `A`s in this discussion, let us denote them as `A1` and `A2`.

For **level = 0**, we should choose a character to be put into result[0]:

- we can choose `A1`;
- we can NOT choose `A2`, because there was already an A encountered before in the list of available chars for this level;
- we can choose `B`;
- we can choose `C`.

First, the algorithm will choose `A1`, and proceed with recursion at next level.

At **level = 1**.

Now, the position associated to `A1` has been marked with a 0 in the `ch` array.
Thus we have the following alternatives for the character to be put in result[1]:

- choose `A2` (because now there is not an `A` available before, as the first one was already taken at the previous recursion level, and marked with `0`)
- choose `B`;
- choose `C`.

It will first select `A2`, and the partial permutation so far will be `A1 A2`, with two more levels to go in the recursion. However, the key for not having duplicates is that for a same character, its indices will always be in increasing order. The algorithm will not be able to also generate a permutation starting with `A2 A1`, simply because `A2` is not allowed to be chosen if `A1` is still available.

Comment: I do not really see how it would work. Can you make any code changes?
So I can run it and see

Comment: @MaharajaX I updated the answer, if there still are some unclear aspects, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple non-recursive algorithm for finding the lexicographically next permutation of a sequence:

1. Scan backwards from the end of the sequence until you find an element which is (strictly) less than the following one. If there isn't one, the sequence is the lexicographically greatest possible permutation.
2. Reverse the subsequence of elements following the one which you found.
3. Exchange the element you found in step 1 with the first following element which is (strictly) greater than it.

I'm not really a Java programmer, so here's an implementation in simplified C++, using fewer standard library functions than I would usually use in the hopes that it is easier to understand:

```
template<typename V>
bool nextPerm(V& v) {
  for (auto i = v.size(); i > 1; --i)
    if (v[i-2] < v[i-1]) {
      std::reverse(v.begin() + i - 1, v.end());
      for (auto j = i - 1; j < v.size(); ++j)
        if (v[i-2] < v[j]) { std::swap(v[i-2], v[j]); break; }
      return true;
    }
  return false;
}
```